# why error ValueError: -1 not in list appears?

Tags: python

Given a sorted array of distinct integers and a target value, return the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,3,5,6], target = 5
Output: 2
Example 2:

Input: nums = [1,3,5,6], target = 2
Output: 1
Example 3:

Input: nums = [1,3,5,6], target = 7
Output: 4

this is the error:
ValueError: -1 is not in list
indx = nums.index(x)
Line 9 in searchInsert (Solution.py)
ret = Solution().searchInsert(param_1, param_2)
Line 38 in _driver (Solution.py)
_driver()
Line 49 in  (Solution.py)

**My Code**

```
   class Solution:
       def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        
           if target in nums:
               return nums.index(target)
        
           if target not in nums:
               x = target - 1
               indx = nums.index(x)
               return indx +1
        
           else:
               return target

**this is the error:**
    ValueError: -1 is not in list
        indx = nums.index(x)
    Line 9 in searchInsert (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().searchInsert(param_1, param_2)
    Line 38 in _driver (Solution.py)
        _driver()
    Line 49 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

why i getting error what is problem?

Comment: **Do not post images of code/errors** -https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: In case the target is not in the list, you’re assuming `target - 1` is in the list. That assumption is wrong.

Comment: and how to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of handling "exists" and "doesn't exist" as two completely separate cases, this can be done with just one simple algorithm:

```
def search_insert(nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    i = -1  # in case list is empty
    for i, v in enumerate(nums):
        if v >= target:
            return i
    return i + 1
```

Simply iterate through indices and values, and when you find the target *or a higher value*, you have found the correct index.

You can condense this to:

```
def search_insert(nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    return next((i for i, v in enumerate(nums) if v >= target), len(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you are assuming `target - 1` is in the list. you can't count on this. To avoid it, find a list of the elements that are less than the target, find the max element in *that list*, find the index of *that* in the original list, and add `1` to it.

```
def target_index_to_insert(lst, target):
  if target in lst:
    return lst.index(target)
  else:
    lessers = [x for x in lst if x < target]
    if lessers == []:
      return 0
    else:
      return lst.index(max(lessers)) + 1
```